# Trouble setting up forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say we have a basic `Contact` and `Call` log model:

**Update**: It seems my initial question did not provide enough detail to explain my problem, I've updated it with a more complete example and details about what I want.

`# Models.py`

```
class Contact(model.Models):
    First = ...
    Last = ...
    Phone = ...

class Log(model.Models):
    contact = fields.Foreignkey(Contact)
    date = ...
    notes = ...
```

`# urls.py`

```
url(r'^logcall/(?P<contact_id>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.log_call',name='log_call'),
```

`# views.py`

```
def log_call(request, contact_id):
    formset = modelform_factory(Log)
    form = formset(queryset=Log.objects.none(),initial={'contact':contact_id})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = formset(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/place')
    else:
        form = formset(queryset=Log.objects.none(), initial = {'contact':respondent_id,})
    return render_to_response('myform.html', {'formset':form,})
```

`# myform.html`

```
<form method="post" action="">
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form.id }}
{{ form.callid.as_hidden }}
{{ form.contact.as_hidden }}
{{ form.date }}
{{ form.notes }}
{% endfor %}
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I get is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="id_form-0-contact" name="form-0-contact">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1011">1011</option>
<option value="31736">31736</option>
<option value="19729">19729</option>
<option value="8818">8818</option>
<option value="19731">19731</option>
<option value="1468">1468</option>
... and so on
    ...
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I WANT from this is the following:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="id_form-0-contact" name="form-0-contact" value="contact_id" />
...
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, everytime I load the page - it calls all the relationship data when I only need it to include a hidden value for the contact the identifies the id based on the value passed from the URL.

Comment: Why? What's the point of a form that only contains a hidden value that you got from the URL anyway? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want the foreign key relationship to be loaded everytime I use the form.

Comment: But that's not what I asked. Why do you want this *at all*? The parameter comes from the URL, you put it in the form, then you get it out again in the view *which already contains the parameter from the URL*.  What's the point?

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to associate a `Log` instance with a `Contact` instance, without loading the ModelChoiceField for the relationship, but instead relying on URL parameters. Or put another way I want a "blank" Log form for that Contact whose primary key was passed in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You load the form with the data...

```
MyModelForm(instance=myInstanceModel)
```

You can make use of instance parameter to instantiate form which will put initial data in the form from that object, instead of providing dict of attributes.

another example

```
object = myModel.objects.get(id=1)
MyModelForm(instance=object)
```

Comment: Apologies, this is not what I was referring to. I have updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a view to **update** your model, What you're looking for is [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

> A view that displays a form for editing an existing object,
>   redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and
>   saving changes to the object. This uses a form automatically generated
>   from the object’s model class (unless a form class is manually
>   specified). -- Django docs

Example:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
```

These might be helpful too:

- [Django Update View without slug in the url](http://pydanny.com/django-update-view-without-slug-in-the-url.html)
- [Django UpdateView sample](https://gist.github.com/flaviamissi/1275204)

Comment: Apologies, this is not what I was referring to. I have updated my question with more detail.